# TFS: How to give permission to NETWORK SERVICE user to allow git push/pull?

Tags: git, tfs, permissions, push, devops

I've got a small script that needs to perform a git pull and a git push but right now it's giving me the error:

> fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://tfs.domain.com/'

The script is located on Machine A. The agent is installed on Machine A.
TFS build is pointing to the script location on Machine A. I'm using the normal "Power Shell" task.

The agent and the powershell task executed via TFS run on the 'NETWORK SERVICE' user. The agent itself was installed/registered via token.

I think the problem here is that 'NETWORK SERVICE' user does not have permission to perform a git push/pull because it's a non existing user on TFS.

A colleague told me it's possible to register the user to access TFS via token or some additional configuration steps are needed on the agent but he doesn't know what and I couldn't find anything online that would help me on this specific issue.

**What steps do I need to follow in order for the user NETWORK SERVICE to be able to git push/pull successfully?**

Comment: What's your tfs version, are you using XAML or vNext build ?

Answer (score 0):

For running git command during build process, you should grant version control permissions of git repo for the build service account.

On the Version Control tab, **select the repository in which you want to run Git commands**, and then select **Project Collection Build Service**. By default, this identity **can read from the repo but cannot push any changes back to it**.

[image]

Grant permissions needed for the Git commands you want to run. Typically you'll want to grant:

- Branch creation: Allow
- **Contribute: Allow**
- Read: Inherited allow
- Tag creation: Inherited allow

When you're done granting the permissions, make sure to click Save changes.

More details please take a look at this official link-- [Run Git commands in a script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic)